# How to make left offset on image so it aligns with text above on all viewports

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to know how to offset an div/image etc. from the left so that this image aligns with the text above.

I have seen it done on flatstudios site http://flatstudio.co/ where the page-header image is aligned with the h1.

I have tried doing this in a fiddle but I can't seem to get this working

See fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/csxqhj8p/2/

```
.top-image {
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1305x630);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 630px;
    background-size: cover;
    left: 58%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    -web-kit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With padding on the left, and the lady's head is a separate image aligned to the right.
It's a trick.

The resize should work thus:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    //do something you like with $(document).width() to make your new padding
    $("#theidofoneofyourdivs").css({"padding-left": ($(document).width() / 10)}); //for example
});
```

Comment: But the wrapper with the black background is aligned with the H1 even though it is resized. Looks like there som dynamic padding controlled with jquery or javascript?

Comment: Looks like it. You can see the code for yourself if you open the console. The padding of the concerned element does change on viewport resize.

Comment: But that's hardly the point, you could have them both (top and bottom) at a fixed distance and the trick would be the same. Unless I misunderstood which aspect of the thing confused you. :D

Comment: I am not that sharp when it comes to javascript or jquery.
Can you point me further to the solution? :)

Comment: hmmm it seems to work better  but on a viewport big enough it doesn't seem to left align with the text in h1 https://jsfiddle.net/csxqhj8p/4/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154630/discussion-between-deg-and-dwtbc).

Answer (score 0):

```
.page-header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.page-header-content {
    padding: 30px 0 88px 20vw;
}

.page-header-text-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 70px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: left;
    justify-content: start;
}

.page-header h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin: 0px;
}

.page-header p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-left: 10%;
    max-width: 460px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.content-image {
  padding: 0 0 0 20vw;
}
.top-image {
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1305x630);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 630px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I don't think adding 60px padding on left and right do it. What if the viewport is bigger or smaller then the div/image would not align?

Comment: You can change 'px' to 'vw' or %

Comment: but would that align with the text above?

Comment: yep : )  you can also change "60px" in both containers  for example to "5vw" ( based on viewport width )

Comment: with alignment of the text I don't mean centered. It should be left-aligned as the above mentioned example http://flatstudio.co/

Comment: Alignment isn't centered, lol. I updated my CSS code. Paste it please in your JSFiddle

Comment: I have tried this, and unfortunately it didn't work.  what . I mean with centered is that if I plan to add a header with a max width of 1170px in to this, then the header, the text in h1 and the div/image would not align as in the above mentioned example

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Use This one

HTML

```
<section class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-content">


        <div class="page-header-text-container">
            <h1>LoremIpsun<br/>Dolerea Est</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</p>
        </div> <!-- page-header-text-container end -->

    </div> <!-- page-header-content end --> 

</section> <!-- page-header end -->

<section class="content-image">
    <div class="top-image">

    </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```css
.page-header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.page-header-content {
    padding: 30px 0 88px;
}

.page-header-text-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 70px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;

}

.page-header h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.page-header p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-left: 10%;
    max-width: 460px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.content-image {
    display: block;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background: #eee;*/
    /*padding-left: 8%;*/
}

.top-image {
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1305x630);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    margin-left: 15px;
    min-height: 630px;
    background-size: cover;
    
}
```

```html
<section class="page-header">
    <div class="page-header-content">
        

        <div class="page-header-text-container">
            <h1>LoremIpsun<br/>Dolerea Est</h1>
            <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard</p>
        </div> <!-- page-header-text-container end -->

    </div> <!-- page-header-content end --> 

</section> <!-- page-header end -->

<section class="content-image">
    <div class="top-image">
        
    </div>
</section>
```

```
.page-header {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 400px;
}

.page-header-content {
    padding: 30px 0 88px;
}

.page-header-text-container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: 70px auto 0px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;

}

.page-header h1 {
    font-size: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.page-header p {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding-left: 10%;
    max-width: 460px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.content-image {
    display: block;
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*background: #eee;*/
    /*padding-left: 8%;*/
}

.top-image {
    background-image: url(http://via.placeholder.com/1305x630);
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    margin-left: 15px;
    min-height: 630px;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

Comment: this still doesn't seem to left align with the text in the h1. On a viewport big enough it seems to exceed the alignment of the text in h1

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because of your last edit. I edited my answer. I added margins to most outer DIVs. hope to be useful for you.

Comment: And if I added fx. a header to this width a max-width of 1170px and centered it, how would the things align? in the above mentioned example from http://flatstudio.co/ you can see the header and text (h1 and blockquote) – they are centered within a max-width and the image-area below align with this - does this makes sense?

Comment: I added code snippet. I made some changes in **content-image** and **top-image** classes

Comment: Now it seems to align in the snippet. But the problem now is that you don't have the image to go all the way to the right. The image now has a max-width. If you look at the example from http://flatstudio.co/ you will see what I mean. I don't think this can be achieved with css only